# Fastlane cannot get console size while init

Tags: android, fastlane, cicd, fastlane-gym

just start my first steps with Fastlane
but when running this command

`fastlane init`

I received this message

```
$ fastlane init
[02:33:16]: Detected an Android project in the current directory...

Looking for related GitHub issues on fastlane/fastlane...

Γ₧í∩╕Å  Fastlane cannot get console size
    https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/issues/20123 [open] 3 ≡ƒÆ¼
    a week ago

C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/3.1.0/reline/ansi.rb:228:in `winsize': \e[31m[!] Bad file descriptor - <STDIN>\e[0m (Errno::EBADF)
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/3.1.0/reline/ansi.rb:228:in `get_screen_size'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/3.1.0/reline.rb:207:in `get_screen_size'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/3.1.0/forwardable.rb:238:in `get_screen_size'
        ...................
```

so how to overcome this issue?

Comment: If you find solution to this, please post an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Hyper Terminal](https://hyper.is).. If `fastlane init` does not work try `bundle exec fastlane init`